# Flutter: how to get location coordinates of point in the center of screen

Tags: flutter, maps, coordinates

I'm using google maps in my flutter app, I want to put a pointer in the middle of the screen so it will be easy for the users to choose the location the look for by just moving the map and making the pointer in the middle of the screen points to the location they look for

so how then can I get the coordinates that sits in the middle of the screen ,exactly the same where the pointer is

Comment: check `GoogleMapController` official documentation

Answer (score 8):

You can do it by using `ScreenCoordinate`:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
```

```
double screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width *
       MediaQuery.of(context).devicePixelRatio;
double screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height *
       MediaQuery.of(context).devicePixelRatio;

double middleX = screenWidth / 2;
double middleY = screenHeight / 2;

ScreenCoordinate screenCoordinate = ScreenCoordinate(x: middleX.round(), y: middleY.round());

LatLng middlePoint = await googleMapController.getLatLng(screenCoordinate);
```

Comment: `ScreenCoordinate` requires the (x,y) parameters to be the number of actual pixels, so remember to take the `devicePixelRatio` into account. i.e.actual number of pixels is width * devicePixelRatio

Comment: screenWidth *= MediaQuery.of(context).devicePixelRatio;
 screenHeight *= MediaQuery.of(context).devicePixelRatio;

Answer (score 3):

You put pointer just by using `Stack`. If you are using `google_maps_flutter` then it has `onCameraMove` argument which returns `CameraPosition` of center whenever the map moves.

```
onCameraMove: (CameraPosition cp) {
        LatLng center = cp.target;
      },
```

Comment: This solution is more accurate, because calculating manually the position varies from device to another according to my test attempts.