# Take maps Lat/Long on centre point of screen

Tags: flutter, dart, here-api

Does anyone know how to take map coordinates from centre point of the screen?

There are several different answers but they're all for Google Maps -

[Flutter: how to get location coordinates of point in the center of screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59430639/flutter-how-to-get-location-coordinates-of-point-in-the-center-of-screen)

I am using HERE maps.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated in the [user guide](https://developer.here.com/documentation/flutter-sdk-navigate/dev_guide/topics/camera.html) simply get it by calling:

```
hereMapController.camera.state.targetCoordinates
```

In HERE's terminology the target specifies the point at which the camera looks. By default, it's looking at the center of the map view, unless it was changed with a principal point.

When the map is panned or moved programmatically, the camera still looks at the center of the map view, so the values are updated each time.